# Having trouble executing a stored procedure

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

When the following VBA code executes it passes the following string to SQL with the world "default" instead of the integer that is needed.  As you can see in the code below, I've even made sure that what is being passed through is an integer by declaring it as such.

When I run profiler here is what is coming across:

```
exec dbo.Dispensing_Days '9999',default
```

VBA code:

```vb
Sub ADO_DispensingDays()
    Dim DayValue As Integer    
    DayValue = Forms("PatientRecordTabbedF").DaysDispensed.Value    

    Call Module4.ADO      ' Opens the oConn SQL connection
    Dim cmdObjCmd As New ADODB.Command
        With cmdObjCmd
            .ActiveConnection = oConn
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            .CommandTimeout = 15
            .CommandText = "dbo.Dispensing_Days"
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PatientID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 16, Forms("PatientRecordTabbedF").PatientID.Value)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Days", adInteger, , DayValue)
            .Execute
        End With
        Set cmdObjCmd = Nothing
    Call Module4.ADO_Close    ' Closes the oConn SQL connection
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code...

.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Days", adInteger, , DayValue)

I missed the adParamInput value.  The code should look like this...

.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Days", adInteger, adParamInput, , DayValue)

I spent way to many hours trying to figure this out.